# Can someone explain the TypeScript syntax of styled()<>()?

Tags: typescript, material-ui

```
export const Flex = styled(Stack, {
    shouldForwardProp: (prop) => calcShouldForwardProp(prop),
})<LayoutProps>(({ center, autoWidth, autoFlex, theme }) => ({

}));
```

I can't explain this syntax to me. I understand what the code does. But I don't understand how it is constructed.
So there is a function `styled(param1, param2)`. Ok
But what comes afterwards?
There is a type `<type>` that is the type of parameters of a function defined in `()` after it.
But what does it mean to define a functiuon after the function call of `styled()`?
So there is `styled()<some type>((params, of, that, type) => result)`.
What is the syntax rule defining something after styled()?

Comment: `styled` returns a function with a generic parameter (and a real one, the callback). Introduce a variable and you'll see there's no new syntax here.

Comment: So I call a function that returns a function, which I call immediately. That function has a parameter which is a function which has a generic parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, function returned from `styled(...)` is generic, but the generic type can not be infered. So you set it explicitly. This way `center`, `autoWidth`, `autoFlex` and `theme` are known and defined - they are derived from `LayoutProps`.
Take

```js
const myGenericFunc = <T>(item: T) => {
  /*Do something*/
}
```

You can call it with

```js
const myItem: string = 'Hello, world';
<string>myGenericFunc(myItem);
```

or just with

```js
const myItem: string = 'Hello, world';
myGenericFunc(myItem);
```

- in any case, it can be infered that `T` is of type `string`. For some cases that's not possible, as in your example. In that case, you should set the `T` manually, e.g. with `<LayoutProps>yourGenericFunc(...)` so inside this function generic type is known and can be used - in your case, to deconstruct the argument.